# MySQL Update is changing input variables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I am trying to update several columns in a MySQL table by using an input form. The code I've written basically looks up all the values in the MySQL table and prints them back as values in a POST form in HTML. The user can then change the values to whatever, and the POST data is processed in PHP and the tables are updated. Everything seems to work except for one column where it's taking the values I'm entering in and it's replacing them with something else. For example, when I enter in 600, it inputs it as 6.00. If I enter 500, it enters it in as 5.00. This is the method I'm using to update my columns:

```
//$D is the array length of $cash_ID
$i = 0;
while($i < $D){
        if(!mysql_query('UPDATE ' .$tablename_cash. ' SET cash_amnt = "' .$cash_amnt[$i]. '" WHERE ID = ' .$cash_ID[$i]))
                die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
        $i++;
}
```

I believe I have figured out why it's doing it, but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. On this specific table, the ID values start at 6 (some elements were deleted a while ago) while all other tables start at ID = 1. I'm not sure why this is causing a problem though because I was under the impression that MySQL simply looked up the row given by the WHERE clause. I can share my full code, if needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is in yoru array `$cash_amnt`?  `var_dump($cash_amnt)`

Comment: I just caught what the issue was. The variable wasn't getting stored as an array and it was causing an issue with MySQL.

Comment: What ever happened to the idea of putting each part of a query on a new line?  I must be old fashioned :(